# Does removing items from a C# List<T> retain other items' orders?

Tags: c#, generics, collections

Lately, I've been writing a lot of code that looks like this:

```
List<MyObject> myList = new List<MyObject>();
...
for(int i = 0; i < myList.Count; ++i)
{
  if(/*myList[i] meets removal criteria*/)
  {
     myList.RemoveAt(i);
     --i;  //Check this index again for the next item
     //Do other stuff as well
  }
}
```

and I just became a little paranoid that maybe List doesn't retain object order at removal.  I don't know the C# spec well enough to know for sure.  Can someone verify that I either am or am not asking for trouble with this pattern?

EDIT: Perhaps I should clarify that the above is a very simplified example and more things happen if the item needs to be removed so I don't think `List<T>.RemoveAll()` is terribly applicable here.  Although it is a nice function.  I have added a comment in the `if()` block above to specifically mention that.

Comment: Just a side note: You should loop through the list backwards instead of forward. Say you remove list[1] (i = 1). This will cause the list to shift, where the element at list[2] is now at list[1]. Now when you jump to i = 2, you've skipped the element that now sits in list[1].

Comment: You should be able to greatly simplify this pattern with the RemoveAll() method

Comment: Why don't you use linq for that?

Comment: @Jason, very good point about iterating backward.  Thanks.

Comment: @chaosTechnician based on your update the pattern in [my response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961606/does-removing-items-from-a-c-listt-retain-other-items-orders/6961649#6961649) should be applicable.

Comment: @JasonDown Instead of going backwards... I'd simply move the "++i" into an "Else" block. Would be more readable IMO. FOR(i=0;i<Count;){if(criteria){Remove} ELSE {i++}}

Comment: @WernerCD: Yes, that works just as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`List<T>` will *always* maintain relative order when adding, inserting and removing; it wouldn't be a list if it didn't.

Here's the (ILSpy'ed) code for `RemoveAt()`:

```
public void RemoveAt(int index)
{
    if (index >= this._size)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
    this._size--;
    if (index < this._size)
    {
        Array.Copy(this._items, index + 1, this._items, index, this._size - index);
    }
    this._items[this._size] = default(T);
    this._version++;
}
```

Note the array copy from `index + 1` to `index`; that's the items being shifted wholesale and "squeezing" the array together. But there is definitely no re-ordering of the elements.

Comment: Aside from the additional (very helpful) conversation about running through the list in reverse and considering `RemoveAll()`, this answers the question I actually asked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You are indeed right, `List<T>.RemoveAt` will not change the order of the items of the list.

Your snippet could however be simplified to use `List<T>.RemoveAll` like this:

```
List<MyObject> myList = new List<MyObject>();
...
myList.RemoveAll(/* Removal predicate */);
```

---

Edit following comment:

```
myList.Where(/* Removal predicate */).ToList().ForEach(/* Removal code */);
myList.RemoveAll(/* Removal predicate */);
```

Comment: This should also protect against the list shifting as each element is removed (skipping the element directly after the one that was removed). I'd suggest moving through the list in reverse order, but his is much better!

Comment: I've updated my original question to say that since I'm doing more than simply removing the item, I don't think `RemoveAll()` will do the trick for me.

Comment: @chaosTechnician - it's likely you could make the code clearer by using `RemoveAll()` and then making a second pass through the filtered list. You could use `myList.ForEach` for that.

Comment: @Daniel, the extra code is only executed when the item is supposed to be deleted (i.e., when the predicate is true), not on the remaining items.

Comment: @Cicada, Wow, very elegant.  I really ought to stop coding C# like it's C++ with easier memory management so I learn about these things...

Comment: The downside to the updated version is it executes the predicate twice for each element. There's a very nice extension method in CLR 4 that solves this problem but it's too long for a comment, so I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 5):

The order should be maintained. A better approach is to traverse the list in reverse:

```
for(int i = myList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(/*myList[i] meets removal criteria*/)
    {
        myList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Or you could use the [`RemoveAll` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx):

```
myList.RemoveAll(item => [item meets removal criteria]);
```

Comment: @Kyle the reverse for loop is easier to follow and doesn't require the index to be decremented once the criteria is met. By starting at the end of the list and working backwards, the for loop will continue to be accurate if an item is removed. As for `RemoveAll`, it's a one-liner with a predicate and doesn't require us to loop over the list and manage the index.

Answer (score 5):

Although the accepted answer is a great answer to the original question, Cicada's answer suggests an alternative approach.

With CLR 4 (VS 2010) we gain yet another approach, which has the further advantage of only executing the predicate once per item (and making it convenient to avoid writing the predicate twice in our code).

Suppose you have a `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
IEnumerable<string> myList = new[] {"apples", "bananas", "pears", "tomatoes"};
```

You need to divide it into two lists according to whether the items pass some criteria:

```
var divided = myList.ToLookup(i => i.Length > 6);
```

The returned object is somewhat like a `Dictionary` of lists. Suppose you want to keep the ones that pass the criteria:

```
 myList = divided[true];
```

And you can use a familiar imperative loop to operate on the other items:

```
foreach (var item in divided[false])
    Console.WriteLine("Removed " + item);
```

Note that there is no need to use `List<T>` specifically. We never modify an existing list - we just make new ones.

Answer (score 3):

From Reflector:

```
public void RemoveAt(int index)
{
    if (index >= this._size)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
    this._size--;
    if (index < this._size)
    {
        Array.Copy(this._items, index + 1, this._items, index, this._size - index);
    }
    this._items[this._size] = default(T);
    this._version++;
}
```

So at least with MS' implementation - items' order doesn't change on `RemoveAt`.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `RemoveAt`, all the elements following the index you remove will be copied and shifted forward.

Sort the positions list in descending order and remove elements in that order.

```
foreach (var position in positions.OrderByDescending(x=>x))
   list.RemoveAt(position);
```

`positions` is the list of indexes. `list` is the one you want to delete from (it contains the actual data).